# What am I doing wrong? access-based enumeration not working with share-subfolders

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share, server-message-block, ntfs

1. Create a share D:\Shares\DATA_AUTH_TEST. Make sure ABE is enabled,
   DOMAIN USERS is granted read permission.
2. Create a folder in D:\Shares\DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER1, Disable inheritance, grant full control to AD Group "USER_1_group"
3. Create a folder in D:\Shares\DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER2 , Disable inheritance, grant full control to AD Group "USER_2_group"

Everyone in the entire domain, regardless of membership or not in "USER_1_group" or "USER_2_group can see \DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER1 and \DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER2.

1. Grant DOMAIN USERS FULL CONTROL

Everyone in the entire domain, regardless of membership or not in "USER_1_group" or "USER_2_group can edit/create files and folders in \DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER1 and \DATA_AUTH_TEST\USER2.

I thought the whole point of ABE was to limit visibility/control of folders within a single share to only those ACL's given permission to those folders? Feel like I'm missing something obvious? Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

Comment: Side note: generally, you don't grant any user group full access. You either grant read-only or modify/create. Full access is administrative, ie. can change permissions.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the folder `DATA_AUTH\USER1` it inherits read permissions from `DATA_AUTH` as it's created. Disabling inheritance does not remove those permissions, they are grandfathered in, which is why `USER_2_Group` can read them. You either have to explicitly remove the `DOMAIN_USERS` read permission on that folder, or disable inheritance to children in the `DATA_AUTH` folder.

It is likely because inheritance to children is still enabled in `DATA_AUTH` that the full control permission propagates to the `USER1` and `USER2` directories when that permission is set.